# $request->input retorna sempre null

Tags: angularjs, laravel

ficheiro angularjs

```
$http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: API_URL + "produto/update" + "/" + produtoSelecionado,
                        data: $.param(obj),
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                    }).success(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        alert(response);
                        location.reload();
                    }).error(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        alert('An error has occured. Please check the log for details.');
                    });
                    location.reload();
```

php controller:

```
public function decreaseQuantity(Request $request, $id)
            {
                DB::table('product') ->where('id', $id) -> decrement('quantity',$request->input('quantity')); 
            }
```

Dá me sempre erro que o valor é nulo tal como está na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já verifiquei o valor da variavel `obj` e ela tem o valor que eu quero mas por alguma razão não passa para o controller. E mesmo que eu coloque um valor fixo ele também não passa.. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar $request->json()->get('quantity') ??

Comment: @SylvioT Já mas sem sucesso. O estranho é que eu tenho outra função que leva exatamente a mesma variável só que em vez de fazer decrement faz increment e funciona bem, só esta é que não